# jQuery Dialog ReOpens after Page Refresh or Page Back

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a GridView with a ButtonField that displays the Project ID for each row.

When the user clicks on the Project ID (ButtonField) it opens a jQuery modal Dialog with a more detailed view of the project. When the user closes the Dialog (using the X in the upper right corner) the Dialog closes and everything is great.

**The problem is:** if the user refreshes the page, or goes to a new page and then comes back using the back button, the page refreshes/reopens with the Dialog already opened. It should remain closed.

Can you tell from my code what I'm doing wrong?

---

*javascript:*

```
// set the <div> "dialog-projectDetails" as a jQuery modal dialog.
$(function () {
             $("#dialog-projectDetails").dialog({ autoOpen: false,
                                                  modal: true,
                                                  resizable: false});
});
```

---

*asp:GridView - I've left out most of the styling:*

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataKeyNames="ProjID"
EnableModelValidation="True" onRowCommand="GridView3_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <%-- Link ButtonType on ProjID to activate modal pop-up --%>
    <asp:ButtonField 
        DataTextField="ProjID" 
        HeaderText="&nbsp;&nbsp;Proj. Id" 
        ShowHeader="True" SortExpression="ProjID"
        ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Select">
    </asp:ButtonField>

    <asp:BoundField 
        DataField="Projects" 
        HeaderText="Projects"
        SortExpression="Projects">
    </asp:BoundField>

    <asp:BoundField 
        DataField="Status" 
        HeaderText="Status"
        SortExpression="Status">
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView> <!-- end GridView3 -->
```

---

*Code Behind:*

```
protected void GridView3_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked.
        GridViewRow row = GridView3.Rows[rowIndex];
        string projectID = GridView3.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        SqlDataSourceProjectComments.SelectParameters["ProjectID"].DefaultValue = projectID;

        string scriptText = "<script type = 'text/javascript'> $(function(){$('#dialog-projectDetails').dialog('open');})</script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "DisplayProjectDetails", scriptText);
    }
 }
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you are opening dialog in anonymous function which runs each time when page reloads.

Comment: First suggestion, Jquery is client-side. C# code isn't necessary and you would prefer to post generated html. Here in your asp part, we don't see anything that fires the creation of the modal. You should not create your dialog in a anonymous function but bind it with a click event on boundField buttons.

Comment: @TCHdvlp - when a user clicks on the ButtonField, GridView3_RowCommand is fired, which runs the .dialog('open').  The dialog displays the div which is loaded with the record for that row. The ButtonField in a GridView doesn't seem to have a 'click' event; the RowCommand performs that function.

Comment: what if you don't open the modal, and just reload the page, or go to another page without firing the opening of the modal ?? Does it opens anyway ?

Comment: I'm not well versed in JavaScript. I will look up how not to do an anonymous function.

Comment: @TCHdvlp - no, if the modal dialog is never opened, reloading the page or using the back button will not open the dialog.

Comment: Ok, so, as it seems to be linked with the server side, I'm afraid there is a sort mechanism that save the data. In a normal form, if you start to fill it and then reload the page, or move forward and back to this page, your informations are kept !! I'm afraid the same appens to you.